# Vert.x SQLConnection: "Unexpected exception in route", "Timed out after waiting 30000(ms) for a reply"

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, vert.x

I'm using Vert.x in conjunction with PostgreSQL.

At the moment I'm attempting to issue a request to the database, but for some reason, although the request is received from the client, it isn't being satisfied.

The error I'm seeing looks like so:

[image]

The strange thing is that, if I shut down the server and restart it, the request will be satisfied.

That makes me think that it has something to do with one of the connections to the database "hanging", and blocking this request.

One other possibility I can envisage is that there's some confusion wrt the routes, could it be?

the routes look like this:

```
Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.post().handler(BodyHandler.create());
router.post("/create").handler(this::createHandler);
router.post("/login").handler(this::loginHandler);
router.post("/account").handler(this::accountHandler);
router.post("/invitation").handler(this::invitationHandler);
router.post("/initiate").handler(this::initiateHandler);
```

I have a theory that the problem could be related to a composite method that makes multiple requests to the database, because the failure always occurs after this method is executed:

```
private void account(Message<JsonObject> message) {
    JsonArray username = new JsonArray().add(message.body().getString("username"));

    JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
    response.put("response", "account");

    friends(friendsResult -> {
        if (friendsResult.succeeded()) {
            response.put("friends", friendsResult.result());

            games(username, gamesResult -> {
                if (gamesResult.succeeded()) {
                    response.put("games", gamesResult.result());

                    invitations(username, invitationsResult -> {
                        if (invitationsResult.succeeded()) {
                            response.put("invitations", invitationsResult.result());

                            System.out.println("ACCOUNT RESPONSE: " + response.encodePrettily());

                            /* * */
                            message.reply(response);
                        } else {
                            System.out.println("FAILED IN <<INVITATIONS RESULT>>...");
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FAILED IN <<GAMES RESULT>>...");
                }
            });
        } else {
            System.out.println("FAILED IN <<FRIENDS RESULT>>...");
        }
    });
}
```

As I said above, it has three "helper" methods, here they are...

One:

```
private void friends(Handler<AsyncResult<List<String>>> handler) { // TODO: Replace w/ concept of <<friends>>...
    List<String> friends = new ArrayList<>();
    dbClient.queryStream(
            sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.FETCH_FRIENDS),
            asyncResult -> {
                if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                    asyncResult.result().handler(row -> friends.add(row.getString(0)));
                }
                handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(friends));
            });
    dbClient.close();
}
```

Two:

```
private void invitations(JsonArray params, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonObject>> handler) {
    JsonObject invitations = new JsonObject();
    params.add(false);
    JsonArray outboundArray = new JsonArray();
    dbClient.queryStreamWithParams(
            sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.OUTBOUND_INVITATIONS),
            params,
            asyncResult0 -> {
                if (asyncResult0.succeeded()) {
                    asyncResult0.result().handler(row -> {
                        JsonObject invitation = new JsonObject();
                        invitation.put("identifier", row.getString(0));
                        invitation.put("user1", row.getString(1));
                        outboundArray.add(invitation);
                    });
                }
                invitations.put("outbound", outboundArray);

                JsonArray inboundArray = new JsonArray();
                dbClient.queryStreamWithParams(
                        sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.INBOUND_INVITATIONS),
                        params,
                        asyncResult -> {
                            if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                                asyncResult.result().handler(row -> {
                                    JsonObject invitation = new JsonObject();
                                    invitation.put("identifier", row.getString(0));
                                    invitation.put("user0", row.getString(1));
                                    inboundArray.add(invitation);
                                });
                            }
                            invitations.put("inbound", inboundArray);

                            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(invitations));
                        });
            });
}
```

Three:

```
private void games(JsonArray params, Handler<AsyncResult<JsonArray>> handler) {
    JsonArray games = new JsonArray();
    dbClient.queryStreamWithParams(
            sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.FETCH_GAMES_0),
            params,
            asyncResult0 -> {
                if (asyncResult0.succeeded()) {
                    asyncResult0.result().handler(row -> {
                        JsonObject game = new JsonObject();
                        game.put("user0", params.getString(0));
                        game.put("user1", row.getString(1));
                        game.put("identifier", row.getString(0));
                        games.add(game);
                    });
                }
                dbClient.queryStreamWithParams(
                        sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.FETCH_GAMES_1),
                        params,
                        asyncResult1 -> {
                            if (asyncResult1.succeeded()) {
                                asyncResult1.result().handler(row -> {
                                    JsonObject game = new JsonObject();
                                    game.put("user0", row.getString(1));
                                    game.put("user1", params.getString(0));
                                    game.put("identifier", row.getString(0));
                                    games.add(game);
                                });
                            }
                            handler.handle(Future.succeededFuture(games));
                        });
            });
}
```

This is the request that is actually failing:

```
private void gamestateRequest(Message<JsonObject> message) {
    JsonArray identifier = new JsonArray().add(message.body().getString("identifier"));

    dbClient.queryWithParams(
            sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.GAMESTATE_REQUEST),
            identifier,
            asyncResult -> {
                if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                    ResultSet resultSet = asyncResult.result();

                    JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
                    String user0 = resultSet.getResults().get(0).getString(0);
                    String user1 = resultSet.getResults().get(0).getString(1);
                    String gamestate = resultSet.getResults().get(0).getString(2);

                    response.put("response", "gamestate");
                    response.put("user0", user0);
                    response.put("user1", user1);
                    response.put("gamestate", gamestate);

                    System.out.println("GAMESTATE REQUEST RESPONSE: " + response.encodePrettily());

                    message.reply(response);
                } else {

                    System.out.println("GAMESTATE REQUEST FAIL");

                    reportQueryError(message, asyncResult.cause());
                }
            });
    dbClient.close();
}
```

Each of the routes is associated with the following handler method, it looks like so:

```
private void handler(RoutingContext context, String headerValue) {
    LOGGER.info("RECEIVED CONTEXT: " + context.getBodyAsString());

    JsonObject data = new JsonObject(context.getBodyAsString());
    DeliveryOptions options = new DeliveryOptions().addHeader("action", headerValue);
    vertx.eventBus().send(dbQueue, data, options, reply -> {
        if (reply.succeeded()) {
            context.response()
                    .putHeader("content-type", "text/html")
                    .end(reply.result().body().toString());
        } else {

            System.out.println("FAIL IN <<handler>>...");

            context.fail(reply.cause());
        }
    });
}
```

Maybe this has something to do with the EventBus? For perspective it is configured like so:

```
@Override
public void start(Future<Void> future) throws Exception {
    loadSqlQueries(); // NOTE: This method call uses blocking APIs, but data is small...

    dbClient = PostgreSQLClient.createShared(vertx, new JsonObject()
            .put("username", "s.matthew.english")
            .put("password", "")
            .put("database", "s.matthew.english")
            .put("url", config().getString(CONFIG_JDBC_URL, "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/wiki"))
            .put("driver_class", config().getString(CONFIG_JDBC_DRIVER_CLASS, "org.postgresql.Driver"))
            .put("max_pool_size", config().getInteger(CONFIG_JDBC_MAX_POOL_SIZE, 30)));

    dbClient.getConnection(connectionResult -> {
        if (connectionResult.succeeded()) {
            SQLConnection connection = connectionResult.result();
            connection.execute(sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.CREATE_USERS_TABLE), createUsersTableResult -> {

                if (createUsersTableResult.succeeded()) {
                    connection.execute(sqlQueries.get(SqlQuery.CREATE_GAMES_TABLE), createGamesTableResult -> {
                        connection.close();

                        if (createGamesTableResult.succeeded()) {
                            vertx.eventBus().consumer(config().getString(CONFIG_QUEUE, "db.queue"), this::onMessage);
                            future.complete();
                        } else {
                            LOGGER.error("Database preparation error", createGamesTableResult.cause());
                            future.fail(createGamesTableResult.cause());
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    LOGGER.error("Database preparation error", createUsersTableResult.cause());
                    future.fail(createUsersTableResult.cause());
                }
            });
        } else {
            LOGGER.error("Could not open a database connection", connectionResult.cause());
            future.fail(connectionResult.cause());
        }
    });
}
```

Happy to provide more detail/context if it would be helpful. Thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 0):

It was something to do with `queryStreamWithParams`, although I don't know what exactly. Finally I solved it like this:

```
private void account(Message<JsonObject> message) {
    JsonArray params0 = new JsonArray().add(message.body().getString("username"));

    JsonArray games = new JsonArray();
    JsonArray friends = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject invitations = new JsonObject();
    JsonArray outboundArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonArray inboundArray = new JsonArray();
    JsonObject response = new JsonObject();
    response.put("response", "account");

    String query0 = "select identifier, user1 from games where accepted = 'true' and user0 = ?";
    dbClient.queryWithParams(query0, params0, res0 -> {
        if (res0.succeeded()) {
            ResultSet resultSet0 = res0.result();
            List<String> pages0a = resultSet0.getResults()
                    .stream()
                    .map(json -> json.getString(0))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            List<String> pages0b = resultSet0.getResults()
                    .stream()
                    .map(json -> json.getString(1))
                    .sorted()
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
            for (int i = 0; i < pages0a.size(); i++) {
                JsonObject game = new JsonObject();
                game.put("user0", message.body().getString("username"));
                game.put("user1", pages0b.get(i));
                game.put("identifier", pages0a.get(i));
                games.add(game);
            }
            String query1 = "select identifier, user0 from games where accepted = 'true' and user1 = ?";
            dbClient.queryWithParams(query1, params0, res1 -> {
                if (res1.succeeded()) {
                    ResultSet resultSet1 = res1.result();
                    List<String> pages1a = resultSet1.getResults()
                            .stream()
                            .map(json -> json.getString(0))
                            .sorted()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    List<String> pages1b = resultSet1.getResults()
                            .stream()
                            .map(json -> json.getString(1))
                            .sorted()
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                    for (int i = 0; i < pages1a.size(); i++) {
                        JsonObject game = new JsonObject();
                        game.put("user0", pages1b.get(i));
                        game.put("user1", message.body().getString("username"));
                        game.put("identifier", pages1a.get(i));
                        games.add(game);
                    }
                    String query2 = "select username from users";
                    dbClient.query(query2, res2 -> {
                        if (res2.succeeded()) {
                            ResultSet resultSet2 = res2.result();
                            List<String> pages2 = resultSet2.getResults()
                                    .stream()
                                    .map(json -> json.getString(0))
                                    .sorted()
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                            for(String page : pages2) {
                                friends.add(page);
                            }

                            String query3 = "select identifier, user1 from games where user0 = ? and accepted = ?";
                            JsonArray params3 = new JsonArray().add(message.body().getString("username")).add(false);
                            dbClient.queryWithParams(query3, params3, res3 -> {
                                if (res3.succeeded()) {
                                    ResultSet resultSet3 = res3.result();
                                    List<String> pages3a = resultSet3.getResults()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(json -> json.getString(0))
                                            .sorted()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                    List<String> pages3b = resultSet3.getResults()
                                            .stream()
                                            .map(json -> json.getString(1))
                                            .sorted()
                                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                    for (int i = 0; i < pages3a.size(); i++) {
                                        JsonObject invitation = new JsonObject();
                                        invitation.put("identifier", pages3a.get(i));
                                        invitation.put("user1", pages3b.get(i));
                                        outboundArray.add(invitation);
                                    }
                                    String query4 = "select identifier, user0 from games where user1 = ? and accepted = ?";
                                    dbClient.queryWithParams(query4, params3, res4 -> {
                                        if (res4.succeeded()) {
                                            ResultSet resultSet4 = res4.result();
                                            List<String> pages4a = resultSet4.getResults()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .map(json -> json.getString(0))
                                                    .sorted()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                            List<String> pages4b = resultSet4.getResults()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .map(json -> json.getString(1))
                                                    .sorted()
                                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
                                            for (int i = 0; i < pages4a.size(); i++) {
                                                JsonObject invitation = new JsonObject();
                                                invitation.put("identifier", pages4a.get(i));
                                                invitation.put("user0", pages4b.get(i));
                                                inboundArray.add(invitation);
                                            }
                                            /* * */
                                            response.put("friends", friends);
                                            response.put("games", games);
                                            invitations.put("outbound", outboundArray);
                                            invitations.put("inbound", inboundArray);
                                            response.put("invitations", invitations);
                                            /* * */
                                            message.reply(response);
                                        } else {
                                            // Failed!
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    // Failed!
                                }
                            });
                        } else {
                            // Failed!
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    // Failed!
                }
            });
        } else {
            // Failed!
        }
    });

}
```

^If you have an idea how to refactor that to be cleaner- I'd appreciate it.